# PHP loop issues with facebook app auth

Tags: php, facebook, infinite-loop, facebook-php-sdk

I am using the latest PHP-SDK(3.11) and i have issues when users come on my app for the first time. The application make infinite loops.
When the user have to give permissions to the application, he is redirected to :

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=**myappId**&method=permissions.request&display=page&next=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2F**myApp**%2F&response_type=code&state=**theSate**&canvas=1&perms=user_birthday%2Cuser_location%2Cuser_work_history%2Cuser_about_me%2Cuser_hometown
```

and when he accept i have the following link returned :

```
http://apps.facebook.com/**myApp**/?error_reason=user_denied&error=access_denied&error_description=***The+user+denied+your+request.***&state=**theSate**#_
```

i don't understand why the access is denied when the user click on "allow".

```
if ($this->fbUser) {
            .... Do Somthing
        } else {
            $this->loginUrl = $this->fb->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                        'scope' => implode(',', sfConfig::get('app_facebook_perms')
            ), 'next' => 'http://apps.facebook.com'. sfConfig::get('app_facebook_app_url')));


            $this->logMessage($this->loginUrl, 'info');
            sfConfig::set('sf_escaping_strategy', false);
        }

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            top.location.href = "echo $this->loginUrl ";
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, since you need to store the access token, one way or another.  Hard to know what you are doing (or not doing) from that snippet.

```
<?php  
# We require the library  
require("facebook.php");  

# Creating the facebook object  
$facebook = new Facebook(array(  
    'appId'  => 'APP_ID_HERE',  
    'secret' => 'APP_SECRET_HERE',  
    'cookie' => true  
));  

# Let's see if we have an active session  
$session = $facebook->getUser();  

if(empty($session)) {  
    # There's no active session, let's generate one  
    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(  
        "response_type"=>"token", //Can also be "code" if you need to 
        "scope" => 'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_photos,user_videos' , 
        "redirect_uri"=> "http://test.com" //Your app callback url 
    ));  
    header("Location: $url");  
    exit;  
}  
// user is logged in
```

Comment: i've trive to add a response_type (token and code). but it dosen't change anything. My redirection keep looping and i still get the user denied response.

Comment: You must ensure that the token is valid.  Instead of redirecting, try to output the errors you get from Facebook when you try to see if the token is any good.